# Terraform command to list existing AWS resources as a Hello World

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the AWS CLI installed on my Windows computer, and running this command "works" exactly like I want it to.

```
aws ec2 describe-images
```

I get the following output, which is exactly what I want to see, because although I have access to AWS through my corporation (e.g. to check code into CodeCommit), I can see in the AWS web console for EC2 that I don't have permission to list running instances:

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeImages operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I've put terraform.exe onto my computer as well, and I've created a file "example.tf" that contains the following:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
}
```

I'd like to issue some sort of Terraform command that would yell at me, explaining that my AWS account is not allowed to list Amazon instances.

Most **`Hello World`** examples involve using `terraform plan` against a `resource` to do an "almost-write" against AWS.

Personally, however, I always feel more comfortable knowing that things are behaving as expected with something a bit more "truly read-only."  That way, I really **know** the round-trip to AWS worked but I didn't modify any of my corporation's state.

There's a bunch of stuff on the internet about "data sources" and their "aws_ami" or "aws_instances" flavors, but I can't find anything that tells me how to actually *use* it with a Terraform command for a simple `print()`-type interaction *(the way it's obvious that, say, "resources" go with the "terraform plan" and "terraform apply" commands)*.

Is there something I can do with Terraform commands to "hello world" an attempt at listing all my organization's EC2 servers and, accordingly, watching AWS tell me to buzz off because I'm not authorized?

Comment: That's not what it's for really, but I see where you're coming from. If you're looking for something read-only but which is a great demonstration of Terraform + AWS, check out https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [data source for AWS instances](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instances.html). You create a `data` source similar to the below:

```
data "aws_instances" "test" {
  instance_tags = {
    Role = "HardWorker"
  }

  filter {
    name   = "instance.group-id"
    values = ["sg-12345678"]
  }

  instance_state_names = ["running", "stopped"]
}
```

This will attempt to perform a read action listing your EC2 instances designated by the filter you put in the config. This will also utilize the IAM associated with the Terraform user you are performing the `terraform plan` with. This will result in the error you described regarding lack of authorization, which is your stated goal. You should modify the `filter` to target your organization's EC2 instances.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't realize that I could simply provide it as part of the `.tf` file for **`terraform plan`**.  I had tried this, but stripped too much out of the data object ... obviously since I can't list things, I don't know what belongs _(I don't have access! But probably not "HardWorker")_. But removing merely the `filter`, leaving `instance_tags` with "HardWorker," got me `Error: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. status code: 403`, instead of `Error: One of filters or instance_tags must be assigned`, so yay.  **`terraform plan`** it is.